# jQuery animate difference between 1.2.5 & 1.7.1

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#element')
.animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -32px"}, 80)
.animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -64px"}, 80)
.animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -96px"}, 80)
.animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -128px"}, 80)
.animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -160px"}, 80);
```

It works fine in Jquery 1.2.5 but in 1.7.1 it only displays the first part (0px -32px) and doesn't continue to animate. What could be the problem? Did Jquery 1.7.1 change something in the `animate` function?

Here is what I'm testing it with:
http://www.kombine.net/jquery/jquery-poof-effect

Comment: Not an answer, but is there a reason why you're animating by chunks of `32px` in multiple steps instead of simply issuing `$("#element").animate({ backgroundPosition: "0px -160px" }, 400);`?
`

Comment: There are quite a lot of versions between 1.2.5 and 1.7.1 that could have changed the way `.animate()` works.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, there is a reason. I need to show 5 different phases of an image in increments instead of just showing the whole image all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [jQuery doc for `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

`{ backgroundPosition: "0px -160px" }` is not a single numeric value.

You can use `background-position-y` with a single numeric value:

```
$('#element')
  .animate({backgroundPositionY:"-32px"}, 80)
  .animate({backgroundPositionY:"-64px"}, 80)
  .animate({backgroundPositionY:"-96px"}, 80)
  .animate({backgroundPositionY:"-128px"}, 80)
  .animate({backgroundPositionY:"-160px"}, 80);​
```

As illlustated here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GEPRR/.

There is also no reason to use multiple, evenly spaced, sequential animations of the exact same property like this.  You can just use one longer animation that covers the whole range that will offer the exact same result with a lot less code:

```
$('#element').animate({backgroundPositionY:"-160px"}, 400);
```

I have no idea what exactly changed between 1.2.5 and 1.7.1, but if you want to use 1.7.1, you need to adapt to its rules.

**EDIT:** Sadly, background-position-x and background-position-y are not supported in all browsers.  You will have to see if it is supported in the browser versions that you care about.

Comment: This works but not as expected. Since `backgroundPosition:"0px -160px"` cannot be used, I will need to find another way to do what I needed. I will accept this answer.